# Why is the output of a call to the_excerpt different when the call seems to be identical?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, excerpt

Ok I've been asked to fix a problem on a website that is a bit weird. The index page (template-magazine.php) [here](http://www.loop-barcelona.com/2013/festival/), Has this bit of code:

```
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
```

to produce a list/grid of latest news and here everything is fine, each entry is represented by a time and place and a snippet of the description of the event.

When you click a category you call the archive.php [example](http://www.loop-barcelona.com/2013/festival/?cat=8) and archive.php has the same call:

```
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
```

to build the list/grid of events. But now the output is time and place as before but the snippet includes the time and date as well.

Now I should mention that the the posts displayed are a custom post type from the All-in-One Event Calendar (by Timely). The problem might be connected to that somehow but I am to much of a wordpress noob to be able to understand that.

The custom post type is added to the loop like this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');

function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_home() || is_tag() && empty( $query-    >query_vars['suppress_filters'] )) {
        if ( empty($query->query_vars['post_type']) ) {
            $query->query_vars['post_type'] = array('post','ai1ec_event');
        } elseif ( 'any' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
            return;
        } else {
            $query->query_vars['post_type'] = (array)$query->query_vars['post_type'];
            $query->query_vars['post_type'][] = 'ai1ec_event';
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

As requested here is the contents of loop.php:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="loop">
    <div id="loop" class="<?php if ($_COOKIE['mode'] == 'grid' ) echo 'grid'; else echo 'list'; ?> clear">
    <?php
        $postedon_data = array(
            'date' => get_option('unspoken_postedon_date'),
            'category' => get_option('unspoken_postedon_cat'),
            'comment' => get_option('unspoken_postedon_comm'),
            'author' => get_option('unspoken_postedon_author')
        );
        $i = 0;
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $i++;
    ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clear'); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-thumb"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail('general'); ?></a>
                <div class="post-meta"><?php if (function_exists('unspoken_posted_on')) unspoken_posted_on($postedon_data); ?></div>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
    <?php
        if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        endwhile; // end of the loop.
    ?>
        <div class="grid-line"></div>
    </div><!-- #loop -->
</div><!-- .loop -->

<?php else : ?>

<div class="loop">
    <div id="post-0" class="post hentry error404 not-found clear">
        <h2><?php _e( 'Not found', 'unspoken' ); ?></h2>
        <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested criteria. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'unspoken' ); ?></p>
    </div><!-- #post-0 -->
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Adding All filters I could find that did something with excerpt:

theme/unspoken/functions.php

```
// Custom excerpt for comments
function unspoken_excerpt($string, $limit) {
$more = '';
$words = explode(" ",$string);
if ( count($words) >= $limit) $more = '...';
$output = strip_tags( implode(" ",array_splice($words, 0, $limit)).$more );
echo $output;
}

// Custom excerpt more
function unspoken_excerpt_more($more) {
return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'unspoken_excerpt_more');
function unspoken_excerpt_length($length) {
return 33;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'unspoken_excerpt_length');
```

Plugin only has an empty functions.php seems to be modelled on MVC instead.
Plugin-file event-excerpt.php has this function:

```
<div class="timely ai1ec-excerpt">
<div class="ai1ec-time">
    <strong><?php _e( '<!--:es-->Fecha<!--:--><!--:ca-->Data<!--:--><!--:en-->Date<!--:-->:', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ); ?></strong>
    <?php echo $event->get_timespan_html(); ?>
</div>
<?php if ( $location ) : ?>
    <div class="ai1ec-location">
        <strong><?php _e( '<!--:es-->Lugar<!--:--><!--:ca-->Lloc<!--:--><!--:en-->Venue<!--:-->:', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ); ?></strong>
        <?php echo $location; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Found something that could be interesting in another plugin file called class-ai1ec-events-controller.php

```
/**
 * event_excerpt function
 *
 * Overrides what wp_trim_excerpt() returned if the post is an event,
 * and outputs better rich-text (but not too rich) excerpt instead.
 *
 * @return void
 **/
function event_excerpt( $text )
{
    global $ai1ec_view_helper,
           $ai1ec_events_helper;

    if ( get_post_type() != AI1EC_POST_TYPE ) {
        return $text;
    }

    $event = new Ai1ec_Event( get_the_ID() );

    ob_start();

    $this->excerpt_view( $event );

    // Re-apply any filters to the post content that normally would have been
    // applied if it weren't for our interference (below).
    echo shortcode_unautop( wpautop(
            $ai1ec_events_helper->trim_excerpt(
                apply_filters( 'the_content', $event->post->post_content )
            )
    ) );

    $page_content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $page_content;
}

/**
 * event_excerpt_noautop function
 *
 * Conditionally apply wpautop() filter to content, only if it is not an
 * event.
 *
 * @return void
 **/
function event_excerpt_noautop( $content ) {
    if ( get_post_type() != AI1EC_POST_TYPE ) {
        return wpautop( $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Found this in /model/class-ai1ec-event.php

```
/**
 * Get excerpt of post content for display in popup view
 */
public function get_post_excerpt() {
    if (
        ! isset( $this->post->post_excerpt ) ||
        empty( $this->post->post_excerpt )
    ) {
        $content = strip_tags(
            strip_shortcodes(
                apply_filters( 'the_content', $this->post->post_content )
            )
        );
        $content = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $content );
        $words = explode( ' ', $content );
        if ( count( $words ) > 25 ) {
            $this->post->post_excerpt = implode(
                ' ',
                array_slice( $words, 0, 25 )
            ) . ' [...]';
        } else {
            $this->post->post_excerpt = $content;
        }
    }
    return $this->post->post_excerpt;
}
```

And that is all I could find on excerpts, hope it helps.

Comment: That filter is poorly written, it is not passing any data back to the filter, it should be returning `$query` at the end of the function and inside the `elseif` statement.

Comment: what is the code in loop.php? also, check the css for any template related styles.

Comment: [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is an action. It doesn't need to return anything. It is being misused as a filter.

Comment: The missing piece of information appears to me to be the contents of `loop.php`. Would you add that please?

Comment: Regarding the css could that really make such a difference? anyways will look into it. (BTW. Theme is Unspoken, Oh and the loop.php is untouched)

Comment: Ok. That is a lot to digest but I don't see anything in the `the_excerpt` filters that would conditionally add a date unless maybe `$location` is a date but that seems unlikely. I do notice that the `the_content` filters are applies to the excerpt, so perhaps research that.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing date related in that code is `$postedon_data`. If these are the files being used as you say then there are a few possibilities.

1. Those `unspoken_postedon_*` values are set in one case and not set in another.
2. The `unspoken_posted_on` function is defined in one case and not another.
3. There is something about the `unspoken_posted_on` function that filters what content it displays based on template or other value.

Those are the only options that come to mind. I suspect the last one.

If you can't work out which it is, `var_dump($postedon_data)` for both cases and edit the output into the question, and post the content of the unspoken_posted_on` function.

Comment: But isn't it the the_excerpt() method that returns something different? I might be a little slow here and I might have formulated my question badly. My problem is that in one case the_excerpt() returns "miniSCREEN es .... etc" and in the other case it outputs "View Map Fecha: 24 mayo, 2013 @ 18:00 – 25 mayo, 2013 @ 20:00 Lugar: LOOP. Hotel Catalonia Ramblas , Carrer de Pelai, 28,08001 Barcelona, España miniSCREEN es .... etc"

Comment: Actually, I don't know. All I can tell from the code is that the only date related items are the ones I mentioned. `the_excerpt` shouldn't be echoing different content. There could be a filter on `the_excerpt` but it is not in the code you posted. It would be worth looking for one though. Are the dates you see above or below the call to `the_excerpt`.

Comment: In the first example some info is skipped/ignored (as it should)

Comment: The well formatted ones are above. And in the unwanted scenario they are repeated.

Comment: It must be a filter on `the_excerpt()` then because I am positive that the date comes from that call and not the `unspoken_posted_on` function.

Comment: A filter would probably be in either the themes functions.php or in the plugins functions.php right?

Comment: Correct. Look for that filter, post it in your question, and I will edit the answer to reflect the information.

Comment: Ok posted all I could find about excerpt and filters on that.